# En un html olvidé poner el DOCTYPE así que se agregaban más estilos de user agent a una tabla... ¿Por qué?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: Estos estilos se agregaron a una tabla dentro de un html sin DOCTYPE]

Estos estilos se agregaron a una tabla dentro de un html sin DOCTYPE

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Al no definir el `doctype` estás "activando" el modo Quirks del navegador, aquí una pequeña explicación de su significado en [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_Mode):

> ... en modo estándar las página son dibujadas de acuerdo con las especificaciones de HTML y CSS, mientras que **en el modo "quirks" tratan de emular el comportamiento de los navegadores viejos para asegurar que dichas páginas se representen de acuerdo a la intención original de sus autores**.

En MDN tienes una referencia más detallada: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

Comment: Mismo enlace pero en español: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode

Comment: Solucionado. Ya está toda la página en español :)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro brutal que hayas traducido la página para contribuir en la pregunta de Shaz. *Chapeau*. En W3schools creo que también hay algo relacionado.

Answer (score 4):

Los "User Agent Stylesheets" varían dependiendo del navegador y se le añaden a tu documento siempre. Sin embargo, todos estos estilos son sobreescritos por tus propias reglas. Los estilos del navegador son por así decirlo, la manera en cómo el navegador representa las páginas por defecto.

Si quieres evitar esto, una manera es hacerlo mediante un reseteador CSS. Los más populares son [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) y ResetCSS.