# FancyBox 2.1.5 Mal posicionado cuando la página tiene scroll

Tags: jquery

Buenas, tengo un problema usando fancy box 2.1.5, pero solo cuando mi página tiene mucho contenido y crece verticalmente, cuando la página no necesita scroll, fancy box funciona bien, les dejo un ejemplo visual:

[image: Fancy box mal posicionado con scroll]

Una cosa curiosa es que cuanto tiene scroll al darle click en siguiente(Siguiente imagen), se arregla el problema y se autoajusta automáticamente. Tambien otro detalle que podria ser relevante es que entre más crece la página verticalmente(contenido) El fancy se va cada vez más abajo, si crece demaciado la imagen ya ni siquiera es visible.

Estoy usando fancy box sin ningún tipo de modificación personalizada, no quisiera ponerle medidas fijas porque me gusta como se autoajusta.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

```
<div style="margin-right:15px;">
   <a class="imgprop" rel="group" href="pepe.jpg"><img width="300px" src="pepe.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".imgprop").fancybox();        
});
```

Comment: Hola @OscarBustos. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías publicar tu código? Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es que agregues un [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, después de un tiempo investigando resulta ser que fue un error de mala práctica, no usé DOCTYPE en mi documento y esto generaba extrañamente el problema.

Tan sencillo como eso, gracias igual.

Recuerden siempre las buenas practicas!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24688/en-un-html-olvid%C3%A9-poner-el-doctype-as%C3%AD-que-se-agregaban-m%C3%A1s-estilos-de-user-agen/24693#24693

Comment: Gracias, ahora ya no es "extraño" jaja